# Swift: (circular?) Gradient View with all colors

Tags: swift, ios10, cagradientlayer

How can I achieve a gradient in iOS showing all available colors, something like this here?

[image]

the black line can be ignored, I'm only interested in the color gradient

Comment: e.g. save a screenshot and embed into an image view.

Comment: that's pretty static, isn't it?

Comment: Even though its static, it would still be interesting how something like this could be achieved in code.